# Creating a summary of a table using GROUP BY and conditional statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table looks as shown below:

```
Category    Year    Step1    Step2   Step3
ABC         2014    Yes      Yes     Yes
ABC         2014    No       No      Yes    
XYZ         2013    Yes      No      Yes 
XYZ         2014    No       Yes     No
```

I need to extract the data that belongs to Year 2014 and print the different print the number of 'Yes' in each step. Something like:

```
Category Year  Step1 Step2 Step3
ABC      2014  1     1     2
XYZ      2014  0     1     0
```

So far I have only been able to Group the data by Year and retrieve count of rows. I am new SQL and it is difficult to find the solution on the internet specific to the schema I have.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  MySQL or MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation.  Here is the MySQL (and standard SQL form):

```
select category, year,
       sum(case when step1 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Step1,
       sum(case when step2 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Step2,
       sum(case when step3 = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Step3
from mytable
where year = 2014
group by category, year;
```

MS Access doesn't support `case`, so you need to use `iif()` instead.